# Where can I find the type annotations for methods of built-in types like set.symmetric_difference?

Tags: python, annotations, type-hinting, mypy, cpython

I know that built-ins for CPython are implemented in C. But I'm interested in the type-hints, or annotations, for the methods of the built-in types.

For example, I'd like to know how `set.symmetric_difference_update()`is annotated. But I can't find it.

It also seems like the built-in functions would need similar type-hints for programs like mypy to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find annotation for `set.symmetric_difference_update()` [here](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/994b69ef8f18e76689daca3947879c3d7f76173e/stdlib/builtins.pyi#L870).

```
class set(MutableSet[_T], Generic[_T]):
    # ...
    def symmetric_difference_update(self, s: Iterable[_T]) -> None: ...
```

Below are some excerpts from the [readme.md](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/master/README.md) file of the `typeshed` repository:

> `Typeshed` contains external type annotations for the Python standard library and Python builtins, as well as third party packages as contributed by people external to those projects.
>
> This data can e.g. be used for static analysis, type checking or type inference.
> [...]
>
> If you're just using mypy (or pytype or PyCharm), as opposed to developing it, you don't need to interact with the typeshed repo at all: a copy of standard library part of typeshed is bundled with mypy.